# on Mac Pro Vagrant cannot find box

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I am on Mac Pro and has VirtualBox 5.1.8 and vagrant 1.8.7 installed in it.

When I try to add a box the terminal gives me this error:

Command: $ vagrant up --provider virtualbox

Error:

The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error:

The "Error" does't indicate anything. Could anyone give me an advice? Thx a lot...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't do vagrant up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/cant-do-vagrant-up)

Comment: Now it works for me. Thanks for ur help.)))))