# Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I just downloaded Vagrant and did the settings as well as install virtual box. I just can't start my project (vagrant up). I have a vagrant file and so on. What can I do?

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'scotch/box' could not be found. Attempting to find and install
...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'scotch/box' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/scotch/box"]
```

Comment: No - the error message in red does not help in this case as it doesn't print the actual error. Run `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG vagrant up` to get a helpful output.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

There seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7970) with vagrant 1.8.7 and the embedded curl version vs the mac os binary (shipped by default on mac os Sierra and others) - remove the embedded one

```
sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
```

Note: you also need to remove the embedded `curl` when you add a vagrant box (remotely or locally) so if you get the same error when running `vagrant box add ....` just remove the curl from vagrant and it will work

Comment: Thanks worked great with 1.8.7 on macOS Sierra. Quite a rubbish problem though.

Comment: Spoke too soon. The actual box download is randomly stalling for laravel/homestead 0.6.0

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that a) this is still a problem as of April 2017 on OSX Sierra and b) that this fix worked and c) Thank you

Comment: how do you "remove the curl from vagrant"?

Comment: that is the command `sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl` - what I meant is that its also necessary if you run `vagrant box add `command

Comment: On Windows, go to C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin and rename the curl.exe as curl.exe.bkp or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update this post. I ran into this error running macOS Sierra and a fresh Vagrant 1.8.7 install and noticed Vagrant just updated. As of Vagrant 1.9.0 this error appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with Sierra (with additional brew installs - which granted could have an impact).

Above sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl did not work still got: SSLRead() return error -36.

Tried suggestion from http://slick.pl/kb/software/vagrant-fix-for-error-60-ssl-read/

Any case:

```
cd ~
cd .vagrant.d/tmp/
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/
vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead
```

Installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error.
In my case I installed vagrant via apt-get which installed 1.7.x..

I removed 1.7.x and installed 2.0.3 directly https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on MacOS Mojave, and Vagrant version 1.9.3, when trying to use the box: centos/7.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'centos/7' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'centos/7' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/centos/7"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

I updated to Vagrant 2.2.5 and it worked as expected:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'centos/7' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'centos/7'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/centos/7
==> default: Adding box 'centos/7' (v1902.01) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/centos/boxes/7/versions/1902.01/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Download redirected to host: cloud.centos.org
==> default: Successfully added box 'centos/7' (v1902.01) for 'virtualbox'!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try update Vagrant to the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiagohillebrandt/vagrant
sudo apt update
```

This will add a repository for your actual ubuntu version. If you are on 20.10 (groovy) replace groovy with focal and call `sudo apt update` again.

Then install vagrant again:

```
sudo apt install vagrant
```

And update all plugins:

```
vagrant plugin update
```