# mac OSX Sierra, can't add vagrant box laravel/homestead, due to needing cURL v 9.0.0 or later, and libcurl.4.dylib providing v7.0.0

Tags: macos, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm on mac OSX 10.12.1 with the latest vagrant installed.

When I attempt to run `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` to no avail. Then I get:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via "vagrant login". Also, please double-check the name.
```

The expanded URL and error message are shown below:

```
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error:
```

Notice that there is no error listed, and it does not mention an SSL issue.

So I tried running `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`. And this is an excerpt of the response I get:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box --debug
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider: 
INFO box_add: Downloading box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box => /Users/brianduggan/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxb899043803582d901582866cb677bf359bdd3a61
INFO interface: detail: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
INFO interface: detail:     box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
INFO downloader: Downloader starting download: 
INFO downloader:   -- Source: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
INFO downloader:   -- Destination: /Users/brianduggan/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxb899043803582d901582866cb677bf359bdd3a61
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl", "-q", "--fail", "--location", "--max-redirs", "10", "--user-agent", "Vagrant/1.8.7 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.2.5)", "--continue-at", "-", "--output", "/Users/brianduggan/.vagrant.d/tmp/boxb899043803582d901582866cb677bf359bdd3a61", "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box"]
INFO subprocess: Command in the installer. Specifying DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 6
WARN downloader: Downloader exit code: 6
ERROR downloader: Exit code: 6
```

The process then continues into running a recovery process where it eventually errors out again in the vagrant downloader ruby file line 206 in 'execute curl'.

Most of the issues I see about this regard Windows and updating cURL, but from what I've read its not a good idea to mess with cURL on mac because other processes may be looking for the prepackaged version. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't do vagrant up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/cant-do-vagrant-up)

Answer (score 51):

I found an answer to this; https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7969 and https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7970.

> I just `sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl` and it works now. It's looked like vagrant can fall back to system's curl.

[Source](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7970#issuecomment-258878119)

and this worked for me.

Comment: no problems, I was scratching my head there for a little while as well.

Comment: I just tried to edit your post to highlight the command, but SO wouldn't let me do the edit due to too few changes... thanks a lot - works like a charm!

Comment: You saved my life! 2 days of searching a solution now have found an end!

Comment: thanks, was going through laracasts and just came across this issue