# Vagrant up OS X Not Working

Tags: macos, vagrant, salt-stack

I have no clue why this vagrant build is not working. I'm trying to build with saltStack tutorial information from https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/fundamentals/index.html

Getting the following error.

The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error:

Operating System OSX
vagrant version 1.8.7

I'm at a loss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog)

Comment: I think the above linked worked. I'm downloading the image now. Thank you for finding this resolution for me, I was unable to find it. I will confirm in a few.

Comment: Now, I getting the following error./opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/provisioners/salt/provisioner.rb:43:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of Object into String (TypeError)
 from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/provisioners/salt/provisioner.rb:43:in `new'
 from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-

Comment: what do you do ? maybe open a new question with the detail of your Vagrantfile and the command you run

Comment: Got it to work, For some reason I had to rollback to version 1.8.5 follow the above link then delete the files located at /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box not found, in a fresh install, in a mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508371/vagrant-box-not-found-in-a-fresh-install-in-a-mac)

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work after removing embedded curl:

```
sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you very much!