# Vagrant box not found, in a fresh install, in a mac

Tags: macos, vagrant

Following the [Getting Started](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/) instructions, I do:

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise64"]
Error:

$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.8.7
```

Any ideas?

I upgraded to 1.8.7 from 1.8.5 (or so) by just downloading the .dmg and installing. I also deleted my ~/.vagrant.d before running. 1.8.7 created its own .vagrant.d when I ran it. Maybe there is something else left from my previous version?

I have virtualbox installed.

This also failed:

```
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise64"]
Error:
```

Their [status page](https://status.hashicorp.com/) says "All systems operational".

I tried an old box, that worked before (a year ago?), and now its broken:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'scotch/box' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'scotch/box' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/scotch/box"]
Error:
```

I think something has changed in vagrant world. Anyone care to clue me in?

Comment: Yes it was, thanks!