# error when using vagrant box add laravel/homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am currently in the process of downloading homestead and laravel. I already downloaded vagrant and VirtualBox 5.x. When I input `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` I get this error:

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error:
```

I tried googling what the issue may be and didn't find anything that helped. I am using a mac if that helps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6764) and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: since I am using a mac it's really hard for me to follow what they are saying  since the person with the issue is using windows

Comment: I have no idea why, but for some reason I thought you were on Windows. Apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog)

Answer (score 0):

As [Frédéric Henri answered on Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40474205/1987830) you need to run following command:

```
sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
```