# Vagrant up not working in mac OS X

Tags: vagrant

I have installed vagrant and a virtual machine provider - VirtualBox. 
https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I ran the following two terminals in my OS X terminal:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant up
```

It gives following error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog)

Comment: I've just tried it and it worked for me on my MacBook. You better check if you're behind a firewall or a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Installing 5.0.28 virtual box version  solved this problem.