# How do I install debian stretch with vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, debian

I try to start a Debian stretch box with `vagrant` on Mac OSX. I changed the box to `fujimakishouten/debian-stretch64` to install this box:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/fujimakishouten/boxes/debian-stretch64

But I get the error: the box cannot be found.

How can I create a stretch Debian VM with vagrant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog)

Comment: if you are using osx + vagrant 1.8.7, check the duplicate question, it should work for you

Comment: @FrédéricHenri: thanks, that solved it

Answer (score 3):

As of now the box `debian/stretch64` is listed at https://app.vagrantup.com/debian

Answer (score 1):

As described here: [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog)

> There seems to be an issue with vagrant 1.8.7 and the embedded curl version vs the mac os binary (shipped by default on mac os Sierra and others) - remove the embedded one

```
sudo mv /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl /var/tmp/
```

This, and using another box:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/sharlak/boxes/debian_stretch_64

solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the box `debian/testing64`.

From [atlas.hashicorp.com](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/debian/boxes/testing64) and it's based on `stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the box `generic/debian9` a.k.a `stretch` available at https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/debian9

To be more specific in term of vagrant commands, for fresh installation you can do

```
vagrant init generic/debian9
vagrant up
```

or in vagrant file put

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/debian9"
end
```

Though, your issue was something else as you mentioned in you answer, but considering the title of question, this might help others (like me trying to install stretch).
Thanks!