# Local Development Environments for Mac

Tags: apache, laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-valet

Ok guys.

Here's my issue. I love Valet, I think it's spectacular. All of my new and recent projects are built on Laravel in some way, most of them are Laravel Spark.

However, my old legacy applications are not built on any framework at all, and all heavily rely on the .htaccess file.

Now, as we know, Valet doesn't use apache in the same way, so cannot run my old legacy applications that I still often need to work on.

I use to run MAMP PRO happily, but this doesn't run side by side with any other environment solutions and just will not work with Laravel at all. It's just not built for it - I don't want to waste time making it work, when it's less than ideal in the first place.

So what I need is a suggestion for a modern local development environment that works great with Laravel applications, but also happily runs all of my old legacy applications. Preferably looking for something that's command based on the Mac.

Any suggestions. I'm really struggling to find something I like. I love the autonomous concept of Valet and would love something like that, or just the ability to run all of my legacy applications with Valet without having to create driver files for each app or anything like that.

Thanks in advance! Love you guys.

Comment: read about:  php artisan serve

Comment: @num8er Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly the artisan server command was removed in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

In my mac I've only `mysql server` and `php` installed.

So when I want to develop/test an app I use:

1) for laravel: `php artisan serve`

2) for non-laravel: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t ./`

3) sometimes virtual box with linux os

4) mostly I use my digital ocean droplet for dev purposes

5) docker (:

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). You could use Laravel Homestead and replace Nginx with Apache as webserver which would allow you to run both laravel and legacy apps, or use a tool like [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com) to build your own box.

To replace Nginx with Apache in Homestead you should follow these steps:

In terminal run:

```
cd ~/Homestead
vagrant ssh
```

Next you'll have to stop Nginx, disable service autoload and install apache:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo mv /etc/init/nginx.conf ~/nginx.conf.bak
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudp service apache2 start
```

Now you'll have to create virtual hosts for your apps in /etc/apache2/sites-available

You could copy the default configuration:
    sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Configure your vhost to something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file and enable the vhost by running `sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

And finally restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

You can find more information on how to setup Apache on Ubuntu [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: I did try going down that route, but couldn't get Homestead to run, maybe because all of the left over junk from all of my previous environments. I'll give it another go. So, would you recommend building my own vagrant box rather than using homestead?

Comment: Homestead is really easy to setup, just make sure you have the recommended versions of Vagrant and Virtualbox installed, and follow the installation instructions in laravel docs. The main advantage of Homestead is that it comes with all the services Laravel uses so you don't need to bother installing them on a custom box. But by all means give PuPHPet a try, it's pretty good.

Comment: I'm unable to add the homestead box to vagrant. I keep getting the following. Have looked everywhere for a Mac based solution to no avail. 'The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error:'

Comment: its a recent issue with vagrant 1.8.7 check http://stackoverflow.com/a/40474205/4296747

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Thanks! That's fixed it.